# Como puedo parar el contador en 0 en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación con un contador, pero no atino a pararlo en 1, alguna idea para poder pararlo y que se quede en valor 0 ? gracias de antemano !

```js
// Declaro la variable contador

let contador = 0;

const valor = document.querySelector('#valor');
const botones = document.querySelectorAll('.boton');
botones.forEach(boton => {
boton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    const estilos = e.currentTarget.classList;

   if(estilos.contains('disminuir') ) {
       if (contador > 1) {
            contador--; 
      }     
   }
    
    else if (estilos.contains('aumentar')) {
        contador++;
    }
    else {
        contador = 0;
    }

    valor.textContent = contador;
})
})
```

```css
.container{
    display: block;
    height: 50vh;
    color:black;
    margin-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

span{
    font-size: 3em;
}
button{
    border-radius: 10px;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:10px;
}
input{
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#nombre{
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
    <title>Ejercicio-1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        
        <span id="valor">0</span>
        <br>
        <button class="boton disminuir"><</button>
        <button class="boton resetear">*</button>
        <button class="boton aumentar">></button>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Introduzca nombre" />
        <button class="boton introducir">Introducir</button>
    </div>
    <script src="contador.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Necesitas agregar un if cuando disminuyes el contador, para que solo disminuya mientras sea mayor a 1.

Comment: hola Emanuel LG la cosa está en que el contador vaya bajando progresivamente, cuando se lo añado el if > 1 se baja directamente, y lo que quiero es que se pare en 0 no que baje del tirón a ese valor

Comment: El if tiene que ser dentro de tu condicion que ya tienes actualmente: `if (estilos.contains('disminuir') ) {
if (contador > 1) {
        contador--;
}
    }`

Comment: muchas gracias Emmanuel LG sirvió tu solución la pongo como respuesta !

Answer (score 1):

El error está en:

```
if (contador > 1) {
      contador--; 
}
```

Cuando el contador es 2, entra al `if` y lo disminuye a 1, pero cuando es 1, la condición ya no se cumple y no entra. Por eso *se detiene* en 1 y no llega a 0.

Si quieres que llegue a 0, cambia la condición por:

```
contador > 0
```

o por

```
contador >= 1
```

Ambas evaluarán a verdadero cuando el contador sea 1, por lo que se reducirá a 0, y evaluarán a falso cuando sea 0, con lo que allí se *detiene* la disminución.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta @jachguate !! me sirvió en uno que era lo que me pedían para la aplicación, de igual manera la guardo para otras, gracias de nuevo !